# Lubuntu 14.04 b43 missing firmware other solutions haven't worked

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lubuntu, dell, firmware

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 b43.

Sorry I seem to have the same problem as many others. I have spent the last two or three days looking for other solutions and tried many of them to no avail.  I get the error `firmware missing` on boot up but it doesn't stay long enough to copy it.

My wireless is `BCM4312 LP-PHY 14e4:4315`. I am running a completely fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04 on an old Dell Inspiron.

I have tried loads of things including:

Fwcutter and firmware installer eg, and I have tried to install it with this code:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

But I have had no luck. Please can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly after trying this before several times, I have fixed it using

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search b43
```

To find the firmware package. Then again:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

No idea what I did differently this time

Comment: The b43 firmware was removed from linux-firmware-nonfree back in late August/early September because of Broadcom licensing